# KB2667402 update fails to install with 0x80004005. Yet it's also showing as installed

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-update

I've got 15 Windows 2008 R2 x64 servers that I manage with SCCM2012. I've noticed during my Windows updates reporting that there's two boxes that are showing as 'error' for total updates installed. Digging around, it looks like the update that is failing to install is KB2667402.

The Software Centre on the server itself shows the following:

```
The software change returned error code 0x80004005(-2147467259).
```

So SCCM thinks it hasn't installed the update. However, if I go to the Programs and Features application and select 'Windows Updates', I can see an entry for KB2667402:

[image]

If I try and uninstall this, I get an error:

```
An error occurred. Not all of the updates were successfully uninstalled
```

If I try and download the patch from Microsoft directly, I get the same error installing as displayed in Software Centre.

The only odd thing about this setup that I can think would affect this is that I run the RDP service on a non-standard port. However, I do this across all the servers, so it seems odd that it would fail on just 2 out of 15.

The tail of the `WindowsUpdate.log` file is below:

```
2012-06-26  15:33:53:184    3924    1608    COMAPI  -------------
2012-06-26  15:33:53:190    3924    1608    COMAPI  -- START --  COMAPI: Install [ClientId = CcmExec]
2012-06-26  15:33:53:190    3924    1608    COMAPI  ---------
2012-06-26  15:33:53:190    3924    1608    COMAPI    - Allow source prompts: No; Forced: No; Force quiet: Yes
2012-06-26  15:33:53:190    3924    1608    COMAPI    - Updates in request: 1
2012-06-26  15:33:53:190    3924    1608    COMAPI    - ServiceID = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7} Managed
2012-06-26  15:33:53:199     860    1198    Agent   *************
2012-06-26  15:33:53:199     860    1198    Agent   ** START **  Agent: Installing updates [CallerId = CcmExec]
2012-06-26  15:33:53:199     860    1198    Agent   *********
2012-06-26  15:33:53:199     860    1198    Agent     * Updates to install = 1
2012-06-26  15:33:53:201     860    1198    Agent     *   Title = Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2667402)
2012-06-26  15:33:53:201     860    1198    Agent     *   UpdateId = {48859BE4-1331-4CD2-8E70-3B537180A0D0}.103
2012-06-26  15:33:53:201     860    1198    Agent     *     Bundles 1 updates:
2012-06-26  15:33:53:201     860    1198    Agent     *       {D854ECF1-99A7-4D67-B435-2D041BF79565}.103
2012-06-26  15:33:53:204    3924    1608    COMAPI    - Updates to install = 1
2012-06-26  15:33:53:204    3924    1608    COMAPI  <<-- SUBMITTED -- COMAPI: Install [ClientId = CcmExec]
2012-06-26  15:33:53:221     860    1198    Agent   WARNING: failed to calculate prior restore point time with error 0x80070002; setting restore point
2012-06-26  15:33:53:222     860    1198    Agent   WARNING: LoadLibrary failed for srclient.dll with hr:8007007e
2012-06-26  15:33:53:322     860    1198    DnldMgr Preparing update for install, updateId = {D854ECF1-99A7-4D67-B435-2D041BF79565}.103.
2012-06-26  15:33:53:325    5700    117c    Misc    ===========  Logging initialized (build: 7.5.7601.17514, tz: +0100)  ===========
2012-06-26  15:33:53:325    5700    117c    Misc      = Process: C:\Windows\system32\wuauclt.exe
2012-06-26  15:33:53:325    5700    117c    Misc      = Module: C:\Windows\system32\wuaueng.dll
2012-06-26  15:33:53:324    5700    117c    Handler :::::::::::::
2012-06-26  15:33:53:325    5700    117c    Handler :: START ::  Handler: CBS Install
2012-06-26  15:33:53:325    5700    117c    Handler :::::::::
2012-06-26  15:33:53:330    5700    117c    Handler Starting install of CBS update D854ECF1-99A7-4D67-B435-2D041BF79565
2012-06-26  15:33:53:342    5700    117c    Handler CBS package identity: Package_for_KB2667402~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0
2012-06-26  15:33:53:366    5700    117c    Handler Installing self-contained with source=C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\44059e0415033d6f699a50ef69dd5ff2\windows6.1-kb2667402-v2-x64.cab, workingdir=C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\44059e0415033d6f699a50ef69dd5ff2\inst
2012-06-26  15:33:56:270    5700    3b8 Handler FATAL: CBS called Error with 0x80004005, 
2012-06-26  15:33:56:402    5700    117c    Handler FATAL: Completed install of CBS update with type=0, requiresReboot=0, installerError=1, hr=0x80004005
2012-06-26  15:33:56:405    5700    117c    Handler :::::::::
2012-06-26  15:33:56:406    5700    117c    Handler ::  END  ::  Handler: CBS Install
2012-06-26  15:33:56:406    5700    117c    Handler :::::::::::::
2012-06-26  15:33:56:433     860    1198    Agent   *********
2012-06-26  15:33:56:433     860    1198    Agent   **  END  **  Agent: Installing updates     [CallerId = CcmExec]
2012-06-26  15:33:56:433     860    1198    Agent   *************
2012-06-26  15:33:56:433     860    d14 AU  Can not perform non-interactive scan    if AU is interactive-only
2012-06-26  15:33:56:450    3924    e40 COMAPI  >>--  RESUMED  -- COMAPI: Install   [ClientId = CcmExec]
2012-06-26  15:33:56:450    3924    e40 COMAPI    - Install call complete (succeeded = 0, succeeded with errors = 0, failed = 1, unaccounted = 0)
2012-06-26  15:33:56:450    3924    e40 COMAPI    - Reboot required = No
2012-06-26  15:33:56:450    3924    e40 COMAPI    - WARNING: Exit code = 0x00000000;     Call error code = 0x80240022
2012-06-26  15:33:56:451    3924    e40 COMAPI  ---------
2012-06-26  15:33:56:451    3924    e40 COMAPI  --  END  --  COMAPI: Install [ClientId = CcmExec]
2012-06-26  15:33:56:451    3924    e40 COMAPI  -------------
2012-06-26  15:33:56:536     860    13a4    AU  Triggering Offline detection (non-interactive)
2012-06-26  15:33:56:536     860    d14 AU  #############
2012-06-26  15:33:56:536     860    d14 AU  ## START ##  AU: Search for updates
2012-06-26  15:33:56:536     860    d14 AU  #########
2012-06-26  15:33:56:539     860    d14 AU  <<## SUBMITTED ## AU: Search for updates [CallId = {2DBB046C-2265-421B-A37B-93BDECC6C261}]
2012-06-26  15:33:56:539     860    1788    Agent   *************
2012-06-26  15:33:56:539     860    1788    Agent   ** START **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates]
2012-06-26  15:33:56:539     860    1788    Agent   *********
2012-06-26  15:33:56:539     860    1788    Agent     * Online = No; Ignore download priority = No
2012-06-26  15:33:56:539     860    1788    Agent     * Criteria = "IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Installation' or IsPresent=1 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' or IsInstalled=1 and DeploymentAction='Installation' and RebootRequired=1 or IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' and RebootRequired=1"
2012-06-26  15:33:56:539     860    1788    Agent     * ServiceID = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7} Managed
2012-06-26  15:33:56:539     860    1788    Agent     * Search Scope = {Machine}
2012-06-26  15:33:58:562     860    1788    Agent     * Found 0 updates and 70 categories in search; evaluated appl. rules of 180 out of 1072 deployed entities
2012-06-26  15:33:58:565     860    1788    Agent   *********
2012-06-26  15:33:58:565     860    1788    Agent   **  END  **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates]
2012-06-26  15:33:58:565     860    1788    Agent   *************
2012-06-26  15:33:58:650     860    f2c AU  >>##  RESUMED  ## AU: Search for updates [CallId = {2DBB046C-2265-421B-A37B-93BDECC6C261}]
2012-06-26  15:33:58:650     860    f2c AU    # 0 updates detected
2012-06-26  15:33:58:650     860    f2c AU  #########
2012-06-26  15:33:58:650     860    f2c AU  ##  END  ##  AU: Search for updates [CallId = {2DBB046C-2265-421B-A37B-93BDECC6C261}]
2012-06-26  15:33:58:650     860    f2c AU  #############
2012-06-26  15:33:58:650     860    f2c AU  Featured notifications is disabled.
2012-06-26  15:33:58:651     860    f2c AU  Successfully wrote event for AU health state:0
2012-06-26  15:33:58:652     860    f2c AU  Successfully wrote event for AU health state:0
```

Answer (score 1):

This thread looks to have a solution that worked for people.

[KB2667402 fails with a 8024200D error in Win 2008R2 x64](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/077be440-7ba8-4597-8841-50bc035992a5)

> Had same problem. The update already exists in the list of installed updates. Removed the update and installed it again

Comment: I can't remove the update. That's the whole point.